# Display a date with letters in foreign language using Struts

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, localization, date-format

I want to display the date using letter (e.g. Saturday, 25 September 2005). With Struts I have to format it like this: `<s:date name="myDate" format="EEEE, dd MMMM"/>`.

But I want to display the date in another language, so I have to use struts2 localization. I am aware about using it for various labels(e.g.`key="global.name"`), but how can i use it for displaying the date?
I want to display `Sambata, 25 Septembrie 2005`, in Romanian.

**UPDATE1**: one way to do it, was to set the default locale to `ro_Ro` in `struts.xml`:

```
<constant name="struts.locale" value="ro_RO" />
```

In this way Struts knows automatically when it sees `<s:date name="myDate" format="EEEE, dd MMMM"/>` that it has to display the date in the default locale language. Maybe there are other options but this works for me for now and I don't have to add a *properties* file.

Still, I have one problem left: I cannot get the date capitalized (e.g. by default I get `sambata, 25 septembrie 2005` instead of `Sambata, 25 Septembrie 2005`). How can I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `i18n` interceptor to set the current locale to romanian. Or do it manually in action or interceptor

```
ActionContext.getContext().setLocale(new Locale('ro'));
```

or using OGNL in JSP

```
<s:set value="%{@com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext@getContext().setLocale(new java.util.Locale('ro'))}"/>
<s:date name="myDate" format="EEEE, dd MMMM"/>
```

Note: `struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess` should be `true` the above to work.

or with pure OGNL in JSP

```
<s:property value="%{new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('EEEE, dd MMMM', new java.util.Locale('ro')).format(myDate)}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I can see that [date tag](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/date.html) accepts an i18n attribute(which will use the current locale by default). You can easily override this with

```
<s:date name="myDate" i18n="ro_RO" format="EEEE, dd MMMM"/>
```

But I recommend that you read about setting the proper default locale for your application or set the request_locale parameter when calling this URL. Changing(and setting explicitly) the locale on each struts tag is just asking for trouble.